# The best way to include a file across multiple files in PHP (for inheritance)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm trying to write a simple PHP MVC framework to play with. Right now, I have some abstract classes defined in a specific file (model, view, controller), which will be "extended" by other classes I create. For example:

```
public my_specific_controller extends controller {
    // some stuff
}
```

However, if I want to do this, I have to include the "main" php file with all the abstract classes every time I want to make an instance of that class. Is there a way around this? Is there a way to make this very efficient and not bogged down by the fact that I'm including this file over and over. I'm new to this side of PHP (used to doing simple things and working within existing frameworks).

Comment: Autoload only seems to work if I have separate abstract class files, which I currently don't (they're all in one file). So including that one file (1 line) would be less than giving each new controller an autoload function (~3 lines). This is cool though, I didn't know this was possible in PHP. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, if I want to do this, I have to include the "main" php file with all the abstract classes every time I want to make an instance of that class.

You need to `include` the parent class file in the file where you *declare* your class, not where you instantiate it. E.g.:

controller.php:

```
abstract class Controller {
   ...
}
```

specific_controller.php;

```
require_once 'controller.php';

class SpecificController extends Controller {
    ...
}
```

index.php:

```
require_once 'specific_controller.php'

$controller = new SpecificController;
```

[Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) can also help to reduce the `require` statements.

Comment: So I really don't have a choice but to include the abstract class file? There is no way to create some form of environment? Almost like a global variable but a global include. I might be way off of what is possible.

Comment: Not really sure what you're getting at. You need to `include` the file that defines your classes *once*. Anywhere. Once PHP has read the file, the classes defined in it are available everywhere.

Comment: Maybe I'm being a little ambiguous. Let's say I have file `abstracts.php` which contains `abstract_view`, `abstract_controller`, and `abstract_model`. The I create two controllers `c1.php` and `c2.php` and a model `model.php`. Each of two controllers and one model need to have `abstracts.php` included so that they "know" what to extend. I'm looking for a way around including it in all of those files.

Comment: That would be to `include 'abstracts.php'` once before you include any of the other files in the file where you want to instantiate the objects. That's terrible dependency management of course. Your only options really are `require_once` or autoloading. Neither is really a problem, you're probably worrying about nothing.